# Repair Suspected TFS database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, tfs

i am using this T-SQL to repair my TFS suspected database

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus [TFS_Projects];
ALTER DATABASE [TFS_Projects] SET EMERGENCY
DBCC checkdb([TFS_Projects])
ALTER DATABASE [TFS_Projects] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DBCC CheckDB ([TFS_Projects], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE [TFS_Projects] SET MULTI_USER
```

but when i use this T-SQL i will get error

> Database 'TFS_Projects' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.

how can i repair my SQL database?

i am using SQL Server 2012

**UPDATE 1:**

this error will Occurred in line :

> DBCC checkdb([TFS_Projects])

**UPDATE 2:**

i have 20GB free on hard drive that my mdf and ldf on it

**UPDATE 3:**

i can not chek Autogrow becuase when i right click on db the error will appear

mdf and ldf is not readonly

and i am loged in by windows administartor, and loged in sql server by sa

Comment: (1) check which part of the error is causing the problem (inaccessible files/No memory). It could be simply you need a bigger Harddrive, or it could be that you aren't running in administrator mode/etc.

Comment: Restore from a backup. that database is toast.

Comment: @RemusRusanu firstly i copy mdf and ldf file from other server, i see that is in suspect state, after that i create backup and restore to other server again it will in suspect state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i update my answer becuase old answer is dangerous and will damage TFS database!
this answer is from microsoft : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620932.aspx

> **To back up your databases**
>
> > Launch TFSBackup.exe.
> >     The TFSBackup.exe tool is in the Tools folder where you installed Team Foundation Server. The default location is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools.
> >     In Source SQL Server Instance, enter the name of the SQL Server instance that hosts the TFS databases you want to back up and choose Connect.
> >     In Select databases to backup, choose the databases to back up.
> >     Need help? List of TFS 2010 databases on MSDN; List of TFS 2012 databases on MSDN.
> >     In Backup Databases to, enter the name of a network share that is configured with read/write access for Everyone, or accept the default location in the file system of the SQL Server you connected to in step 2.
> >     Note Note
> >     If you want to overwrite backups stored in this network location, you can choose Overwrite existing database backups at this location.
> >     Choose Backup Now.
> >     The Backup tool reports progress on each database being backed up.
> >     Choose Close.
> >     Restore your data
>
> **To restore your TFS data**
>
> > Launch TFSRestore.exe.
> >     The TFSRestore.exe tool is in the Tools folder where you installed Team Foundation Server. The default location is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools.
> >     In Target SQL Server Instance, enter the SQL Server instance you will use as the data tier and choose Connect.
> >     Choose Add Share and enter the UNC path to the network share that is configured with read/write access to Everyone where you stored the backups of your TFS data. For example, \servername\sharename.
> >     If the backup files are located on the file system of the server that is running TFSRestore.exe, you can use the drop down box to select a local drive.
> >     Note Note
> >     The service account for the instance of SQL Server you identified at the start of this procedure must have read access to this share.
> >     In the left hand navigation pane, choose the network share or local disk you identified in the previous step.
> >     The TFS Restore Tool displays the database backups stored on the file share.
> >     Select the check boxes for the databases you want to restore to the SQL Server you identified at the start of this procedure.
> >     Important note Important
> >     For SharePoint, you must only restore the WSS_Content database. Do not restore the WSS_AdminContent or WSS_Config databases. You want the new SharePoint Foundation versions of these databases, not the ones from the previous version of SharePoint or from a SharePoint installation running on any other server.
> >     Choose Overwrite the existing database(s) and then choose Restore.
> >     The Database Restore Tool restores your data and displays progress reports.
> >     Choose Close.

Comment: You really need to talk to MS support. Running any SQL against your TFS databases that you did not get from the TFS team effectively voids your warranty.

Comment: @MrHinsh sadly yes! you right because i can not define database to team foundation! thank you

Comment: @MrHinsh finally i found solution, i update my answer

Answer (score 1):

1) If possible add more hard drive space either by removing of unnecessary files from hard drive or add new hard drive with larger size.

2) Check if the database is set to Autogrow on.

3) Check if the account which is trying to access the database has enough permission to perform operation.

4) Make sure that .mdf and .ldf file are not marked as read only on operating system file system level.

Found here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/02/sql-server-fix-error-945-database-cannot-be-opened-due-to-inaccessible-files-or-insufficient-memory-or-disk-space-see-the-sql-server-error-log-for-details/

Comment: i have 20GB free space, i can not chek Autogrow becuase when i right click on db the error that i say will appear, mdf and ldf is not readonly, and i am loged in by windows administartor, and loged in sql server by sa

Answer (score 0):

Probably your database is corrupt either due to an unexpected server restart or filesystem corruption. You can use `CheckDB` to check for issues & remove the suspect status. However, the best bet is to restore it from a working backup.

Some reasons for when this happens are

1. Database is corupted
   database files are being "opened" or held by some process (operating system, other program(s)...)
2. Not enough disk space for SQL Server
3. Insufficient memory (RAM) for SQL Server
4. Unexpected SQL Server shutdown caused by power failure

[How to repair a suspect database](http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/sql-server-development/how-to-repair-a-suspect-database-in-sql-server)

Comment: i have this database, in one server without suspected state, firstly i copy mdf and ldf file from other server to new server, i see that is in suspect state, after that i create backup and restore to new server agin it will in suspect state...

Comment: @EmranSadeghi restore from a previous copy. You can remove it from suspect state if you see the link I posted.

Comment: i see link and flow instraction that you say, thank you, but it is not helped me, this problem is for backed up database from compressed tables, firstly i disable compression, and after that, my problem solved, thanks again

Comment: @EmranSadeghi glad its solved, when there is a will theres a way =)